# How to say "whoever's"?

Tags: grammar, sentence-construction, pronouns, possessives

Please look at the following example:
If someone asks me to not upvote a question (suppose) and I want to tell them in response that "I will upvote **whoever's** question I want".

How to express this? The bold word sound wrong to me. But I want to say that I will upvote any question I want. Is my sentence wrong? How to fix this problem please?

Comment: The awkwardness of a phrase can often be side-stepped by finding another way to say it. "I will upvote any question I want" as you wrote.

Comment: [Related](https://english.stackexchange.com/q/602701).

Answer (score 2, accepted):

There is a word "whosever" but it is not often heard. ([Lexico](https://www.lexico.com/definition/whosever) labels it "rare".)

"Whoever's" is correct.

However, "whoever's" is only suitable if you are being told not to upvote a question on the grounds of who wrote it. Otherwise, it is better to say "whichever question".

Comment: I didn't know till date that "whoever's" was even a word in English. I use _whosever_ more than rare occasions.

Comment: "Whosever" isn't wrong, but it is rare now in Britain, and I understand the same is true of the United States. Perhaps it is more commonly used in India.

Comment: I don't know about everyone, not even the majority, but I can speak for myself, and I do use some rare words now and then (which are grammatically correct and present in almost all dictionaries).

Comment: Nothing wrong with using rare words. That said, the fact that Oxford marks it as "rare" may mean that if you use it in ordinary everyday conversation, it will sound stilted to some listeners in the UK.

Comment: Thank you rjpond. You have been very helpful.